# Showing counit of adjunction is epic

Tags: category-theory

If you have a free/forgetful adjunction between Set and Mon, how would you go about proving the counit of this adjunction is epic?

Comment: Well, you should describe the counit. What have you got so far?

Comment: Suppose we have free functor A: Sets -> Mon and forgetful functor B: Mon -> Sets. Then we can call the counit of this adjunction C so that C: A(B(M)) -> M where M is some monoid in Mon